# Random variables, calculating probability for an event occurring after a number of attempts

Tags: statistics, random-variables

> A monkey is sitting at a simplified keyboard that only includes the
>   keys “a”, “b”, and “c”. The monkey presses the keys at random. Let X
>   be the number of keys pressed until the monkey has pressed all the
>   different keys at least once. For example, if the monkey typed
>   “accaacbcaaac. . . ” then X would equal 7 whereas if the monkey typed
>   “cbaccaabbcab. . . ” then X would equal 3.
>
> 1) What’s the probability X = 3?
>
> 2) How many sequences are there of length nine that use at most two of the different keys? Hint: Be careful you don’t double
>   count!
>
> 3) What’s the probability X ≥ 10?

For (1), I answered: 1 * 1/2 * 1/3. I did this using my intuition, but I was wondering if there was a formula for this?

For (2), I answered (9 ^ 2).

I'm completely stuck on (3) though. How would I approach this?

Comment: The stirling numbers of the second kind are very useful to solve the so-called coupon-collector-problem. The probability that $n$ objects all occured after $k$ trials is $\frac{S(k,n)\cdot n!}{n^k}$ for $k\ge n$, where $S(k,n)$ is the stirling number of the second kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula for $P(x=3)$ : $\frac{3!}{3^3}=\frac{6}{27}=\frac{2}{9}$. In the second step, we have probability $\frac{2}{3}$ to get a new letter.

Number of strings with length $9$ using one letter : $3$

Number of strings with length $9$ using exactly two letters : $3\cdot (2^9-2)=1530$ strings, in total $1533$ strings out of $3^9=19683$ strings without all letters.

Use this result to solve the last part.

Comment: Why is it 2^9 - 2? Where did the (-2) come from?

Comment: I have to exclude the two sequences only containing one letter.